# Segmentation fault during pthread_join

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads

```
#define SIZE 3 
#define MAX_THREADS 9 
int main() {

    ...

    pthread_t m_threads[MAX_THREADS];
    int t_num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {

            ...

            pthread_create(&m_threads[i], NULL, multiply, (void *) &td[t_num]);
            t_num++;
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++ ) {
        pthread_join(m_threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am creating 9 threads to do some matrix multiplication. The calculations are successful. But the program crashes when I try to join the threads. The program crashes while performing `pthread_join(m_threads[i], NULL)` during the 4th iteration of the for-loop.

Debugging the program I get this segmentation fault from GDB.

```
Thread 1 "Pthread" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f7d0063ac9f in __free_tcb () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

Comment: You're using uninitialized elements of your `m_threads` array like they were valid.

Comment: Instead of `pthread_create(&m_threads[i]`, did you mean `pthread_create(&m_threads[t_num]` ?

Comment: `pthread_create(&m_threads[i]` should be `pthread_create(&m_threads[t_num]`

Comment: @AlanBirtles and others. Thank you for your help. What a silly error on my part.

Comment: what if MAX_THREADS > SIZE*SIZE ? Can you join a thread that hasn't been launched?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `pthread_create(&m_threads[i]` to `pthread_create(&m_threads[t_num]` solved the issue.